# Determine the inner width of a ScrollViewer

Tags: .net, wpf, layout

I have a `<ScrollViewer>` in a WPF application on .NET Framework 4.7. Inside that ScrollViewer is a `<Border>`. That border doesn't necessarily take up all the space it gets. A `ScaleTransform` is applied to it to allow zooming in and out.

When zooming in and out with the mouse wheel, the content position under the mouse cursor should remain the same, for the old and new scaling. For this, I need to do some maths to determine where the mouse cursor is in the old and new scaling.

I already have the scroll position of the ScrollViewer, but I can't find the virtual or scrollable or content width/height of the ScrollViewer. How can I determine the total width or height of the content area of the ScrollViewer? That is the minimum size when no scrollbars would be displayed. I can't just use the actual size of the inner Border because that is constrained and may not fill the scrollable area in both dimensions. I need to get that information directly from the ScrollViewer or its scrollbars (which I have no access to).

Here's a part of the XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel">
    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="100">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform .../>
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <dt:DrawingCanvas .../>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</scrollViewer>
```

The DrawingCanvas is the object that determines the size. It's horizontally and vertically centered in the scroll viewer. If it exceeds the available screen space in one or both dimensions, a scrollbar appears.

I'm using this code to get the current position in the `ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel` event handler:

```
private void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs args)
{
    // Determine the mouse cursor position relative to the content
    var sv = (ScrollViewer)sender;
    Point mousePoint = args.GetPosition(sv);
    double x = mousePoint.X + sv.HorizontalOffset;
    double y = mousePoint.Y + sv.VerticalOffset;
    double xFrac = x / sv.ContentWidth;
    double yFrac = y / sv.ContentHeight;

    // Updating scale factor and layout...

    // Move scrollbars to keep the same content under the mouse cursor
    sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(...);
    sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(...);
}
```

Specifically I'm looking for the non-existent properties of `ContentWidth` and `ContentHeight` from the scroll viewer. How can I get those values?

Comment: Are you looking for **sv.ExtentHeight** or **sv.ExtentWidth**?

Comment: I have updated my answer. From what I understood you simply want to zoom in and out at mouse pointer position. I have created an attached behavior to encapsulate the feature. The behavior works with every `FrameworkElement`, not only with `Canvas`. Please read my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The ScrollViewer is described as follows:

`ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth` returns the pure visible content area.
Content elements that doesn't fit into the `ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth` are clipped and the horizontal scroll bar may show (if not disabled). In this case the `ScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth` will return the hidden/clipped part of the content width, the part that can be scrolled into the viewport.
For example, if the `ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth` returns `50` and the content has a width of `60`, then the content will be clipped at `50` and `ScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth` will return `10`:

```
scrollable_width = content_width - viewport_width = 60 - 50 = 10
```

`ScrollViewer.ExtentWidth` will show you the total width, which is equivalent to the content's width. In case the content exceeds the width of the viewport, `ScrollViewer.ExtentWidth` can be also described by the sum of `ScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth` and `ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth`:

```
ScrollViewer.ExtentWidth = scroll_viewer_content_width

Or

ScrollViewer.ExtentWidth = ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth + ScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth.
```

`ScrollViewer.ActualWidth` will return the current width of the `ScrollViewer` control itself (without the hidden/clipped content part but including the scroll bars).

Everything discussed so far applies to the `ScrolViewer` related height values too.

Regarding your desired zoom feature:

The scaling should target the `Canvas`. You can scale the `Canvas` at mouse cursor position by setting the `ScaleTransform.CenterX` and
`ScaleTransform.CenterY` to the current mouse position. Scaling will trigger a layout pass, which will trigger the `ScrollViewer` to adjust to the changed content. This requires to reposition the content by scrolling to the new position in order to avoid the content to be scrolled away from the scaling origin.

The scaling factor applies to the complete coordinate system relative to the scaled element e.g., `Canvas`.
This means when the mouse position is at *P1(5;5)* and a scaling factor of 2 is applied, the mouse position will move to *P2(10;10)*. The new mouse position *P2* describes the offset that must be added to the current `ScrollViewer` offsets in order to keep the zoomed object in place:

```
horizontal_scroll_offset = Pmouse_X * scaleFactor + current_horizontal_scroll_offset

and

vertical_scroll_offset = Pmouse_Y * scaleFactor + current_vertical_scroll_offset
```

In order to scroll the the `ScrollViewer` by pixels (mouse position is returned in pixels), the `ScrollViewer` must be configured to use physical scrolling units instead of logical units. `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` must be set to `false` (which is the default).
Also the `PreviewMouseWheel` event handler needs to have access to the `ScaleTransform` of the `Canvas` (or `FrameworkElement` in general) in order to know the scale factor and to the `ScrollViewer` in order to adjust the scroll offset after applying the scaling. The access could be either directly or via data binding.

For convenience, I have created an attached behavior `ZoomBehavior`.
This behavior zooms in and out every element that is a `FrameworElement` on mouse wheel input.

To enable zoom, set the `ZoomBehavior.IsEnabled` to `true`.
Optionally, set the zoom factor `ZoomBehavior.ZoomFactor` (default is `0.1`).
Optionally, bind or set a `ScrollViewer` to `ZoomBehavior.ScrollViewer`, if you wish to adjust scroll position. Note that `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` should be set to `false` for proper behavior.

The following example enables zooming on a `Canvas` element:

```
ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" 
             CanContentScroll="False" 
             Width="500" Height="500"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <Canvas Width="300" Height="300"
          main:ZoomBehavior.IsEnabled="True"
          main:ZoomBehavior.ZoomFactor="0.1"
          main:ZoomBehavior.ScrollViewer="{Binding ElementName=ScrollViewer}"
          Background="DarkGray">
    <Ellipse Fill="DarkOrange" 
             Height="100" Width="100" 
             Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="100" />
  </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**ZoomBehavior.cs**
The code uses a [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression), which is a feature of C# 8.0.
If your environment doesn't support this language version, you need to convert the expression to a classic `switch` statement (with two labels).

```
public class ZoomBehavior : DependencyObject
{
  #region IsEnabled attached property

  // Required
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(ZoomBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnIsEnabledChanged));
  
  public static void SetIsEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement, bool value) => attachingElement.SetValue(ZoomBehavior.IsEnabledProperty, value);

  public static bool GetIsEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement) => (bool) attachingElement.GetValue(ZoomBehavior.IsEnabledProperty);

  #endregion

  #region ZoomFactor attached property

  // Optional
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoomFactorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "ZoomFactor", typeof(double), typeof(ZoomBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(0.1));

  public static void SetZoomFactor(DependencyObject attachingElement, double value) => attachingElement.SetValue(ZoomBehavior.ZoomFactorProperty, value);

  public static double GetZoomFactor(DependencyObject attachingElement) => (double) attachingElement.GetValue(ZoomBehavior.ZoomFactorProperty);

  #endregion

  #region ScrollViewer attached property

  // Optional
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollViewerProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "ScrollViewer", typeof(ScrollViewer), typeof(ZoomBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(ScrollViewer)));

  public static void SetScrollViewer(DependencyObject attachingElement, ScrollViewer value) => attachingElement.SetValue(ZoomBehavior.ScrollViewerProperty, value);

  public static ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject attachingElement) => (ScrollViewer) attachingElement.GetValue(ZoomBehavior.ScrollViewerProperty);

  #endregion
  private static void OnIsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!(attachingElement is FrameworkElement frameworkElement))
    {
      throw new ArgumentException("Attaching element must be of type FrameworkElement");
    }

    bool isEnabled = (bool) e.NewValue;
    if (isEnabled)
    {
      frameworkElement.PreviewMouseWheel += ZoomBehavior.Zoom_OnMouseWheel;
      if (ZoomBehavior.TryGetScaleTransform(frameworkElement, out _))
      {
        return;
      }

      if (frameworkElement.LayoutTransform is TransformGroup transformGroup)
      {
        transformGroup.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform());
      }
      else
      {
        frameworkElement.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform();
      }
    }
    else
    {
      frameworkElement.PreviewMouseWheel -= ZoomBehavior.Zoom_OnMouseWheel;
    }
  }

  private static void Zoom_OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
  {
    var zoomTargetElement = sender as FrameworkElement;

    Point mouseCanvasPosition = e.GetPosition(zoomTargetElement);
    double scaleFactor = e.Delta > 0
      ? ZoomBehavior.GetZoomFactor(zoomTargetElement)
      : -1 * ZoomBehavior.GetZoomFactor(zoomTargetElement);
    
    ZoomBehavior.ApplyZoomToAttachedElement(mouseCanvasPosition, scaleFactor, zoomTargetElement);

    ZoomBehavior.AdjustScrollViewer(mouseCanvasPosition, scaleFactor, zoomTargetElement);
  }

  private static void ApplyZoomToAttachedElement(Point mouseCanvasPosition, double scaleFactor, FrameworkElement zoomTargetElement)
  {
    if (!ZoomBehavior.TryGetScaleTransform(zoomTargetElement, out ScaleTransform scaleTransform))
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("No ScaleTransform found");
    }

    scaleTransform.CenterX = mouseCanvasPosition.X;
    scaleTransform.CenterY = mouseCanvasPosition.Y;

    scaleTransform.ScaleX = Math.Max(0.1, scaleTransform.ScaleX + scaleFactor);
    scaleTransform.ScaleY = Math.Max(0.1, scaleTransform.ScaleY + scaleFactor);
  }

  private static void AdjustScrollViewer(Point mouseCanvasPosition, double scaleFactor, FrameworkElement zoomTargetElement)
  {
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = ZoomBehavior.GetScrollViewer(zoomTargetElement);
    if (scrollViewer == null)
    {
      return;
    }

    scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + mouseCanvasPosition.X * scaleFactor);
    scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset + mouseCanvasPosition.Y * scaleFactor);
  }

  private static bool TryGetScaleTransform(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, out ScaleTransform scaleTransform)
  {
    // C# 8.0 Switch Expression
    scaleTransform = frameworkElement.LayoutTransform switch
    {
      TransformGroup transformGroup => transformGroup.Children.OfType<ScaleTransform>().FirstOrDefault(),
      ScaleTransform transform => transform,
      _ => null
    };

    return scaleTransform != null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've looked around a little more and it seems that `sv.ScrollableWidth + sv.ViewportWidth` is the value I need. `sv.ExtentWidth` only covers the content, even if it's smaller than the available space.

Comment: It depends. You asked for the visible area and this is the viewport. So `ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth` returns the pure visible area. Some items that don't fit are clipped and the horizontal scroll bar may show (if not disabled). If items don't fit into the visible area, the `ScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth` will return the hidden/clipped item width, that can be scrolled into the viewport. `ScrollViewer.ExtentWidth` will show you the total width, which is equivalent to max item width.

Comment: It's `ScrollViewer.ExtentWidth = ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth + ScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth`. This translates to _total_width = visible_width + clipped_max_width_. `ScrollViewer.ActualWidth` will return the current width of the pure `ScrollViewer` without the hidden/clipped content.

Comment: Well, I guess you misunderstood my question, but I can't blame you for that. I should have drawn a picture, especially when terminology isn't clear. And your equation isn't always true. `ExtentWidth` can be smaller than the sum of the other two, if the scrollviewer's content is smaller than the available viewport size. That's why I wrote I needed the sum of the two, not `ExtentWidth`.

Comment: That's true. When the item's width is smaller than the viewport width, then `ExtendWidth` is equal to the item's width. We can generally say that the ÈxtendWidth` is always equal to the item's width. Item's width is split up into a visible part (`ViewportWidth`)  and a hidden part (`ScrollableWidth`). If my answer is not satisfying I obviously misunderstood your problem. I will take one more look at your question.

Comment: I have updated my answer. From what I understood you simply want to zoom in and out at mouse pointer position. I have created a behavior to encapsulate the feature. The behavior works with every `FrameworkElement`. Please read my updated answer.